# django formset causing ValidationError

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am having trouble with using django formset. Making a POST request is causing ValidationErrors with the form. I looked at the other posts on SO and but none of the answers worked for me. Any ideas ?

```
class CompileTime(models.Model):
    changelist         = models.ForeignKey(Changelist)
    corpus             = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    frequency          = models.IntegerField()
    asmTollvmIR        = models.OneToOneField(TimeStatObj, related_name = "asmTollvmIR")
    optimizationPasses = models.OneToOneField(OptimizationPassesTimeStat)

CompileTimeForm = modelformset_factory(CompileTime)
```

My views.py looks like this.

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_form_data(request, formsetclass, custom_logic=None):
    response_obj = create_response(False)
    print formsetclass

    if (request.method == "POST"):
        try:
            formset = formsetclass(data=request.POST)
        except ValidationError:
            formset = None

        print formset
        if (formset and formset.is_valid()):
            if (custom_logic != None):
                response_obj = custom_logic(formset, response_obj)

            response_obj.update({"status": 0})
            return json_response_from(response_obj)
        else:
            response_obj.update({"status":-1, "response_message": "Form is invalid"})
            return json_response_from(response_obj)

    elif (request.method == "GET"):
        formset = formsetclass()
        return render_to_response("dashboard/show_form.html",
                                  {"formset": formset},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@csrf_exempt
def add_compile_time_stats(request):
    return add_form_data(request, CompileTimeForm, save_form)
```

The template looks like this.

```
<form action="/dashboardMain/add_changelist" method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" /> <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I realized was I was not returning from the add_compile_time_stats function. Adding  return statement caused the problems to go away. :)
Should have looked at that before.